# I am using jquery validator, and need help writing my own addMethod( name, method, message,) to valid a promotional code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to be able to validate a form field called promotional codes, without using a data base.

There are two valid codes and the forms field needs to match either one of these. They are codes like this 'VK2012'.

I've tried the equalto with a hidden form field but this doesn't quite work.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want to do this on the client side not the server side? Users would potentially be able to hack the promotional codes out of your script. (However a jQuery validator to match one of two fixed strings is an interesting problem in itself.)

Comment: Be careful, a user can change what is in a hidden input or in your javascript.

Comment: Can it be done using an asp script? I don't have access to a data base.

Comment: Validation *is* useful to check if a code meets a certain pattern, like /[\w]{2}[\d]{4}/, but don't check to see if it matches a specific value for the reasons listed above.  That has to be done on the server side or you'll make it too easy for a user to discover your valid codes and take advantage of your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the comments are right.  You should do this on the server side.  Client side validation of this sort really ought to be reserved for the case where you can safely assume that your users are acting in good faith (and as soon as you're talking about things like promotional codes, you cannot assume that).  As far as a non-database solution goes, it's ugly and maintains poorly, but you could always hardwire the strings to compare to into the code on the server side.  Alternately, for a somewhat less ugly (but somewhat more involved) version, you could put them into config files, which would let you change the codes without recompiling.

Comment: Many thanks Ben< I think I'll have to find a server side solution to this.